# Getting position of pdfptable

Tags: vb.net, itext

in my document I am creating 3-4 pdfptables.

At design time I don't know the size of the tables. I need to place the 2nd table right after the first, but I dont know the position of the first (I can't calculate it because I dont know how big it is). How do I know where to place the second table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out the total height of the table dynamically. After you use the `WriteSelectedRows()` function, you can call the `.TotalHeight()` property to find out how tall your table was (in points). Then figure out with some calculations where it ends and where the next one should begin.

Comment: thanks very much! please help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375677/itextsharp-pdfptables-are-running-into-each-other

Answer (score 0):

That's right the table height and width is dynamically calculated, but you don't have to call `WriteSelectedRows()` function. You have to set either height or width.

In my case I had to first calculate that if font used can fill the page if not I had to dynamically change the font appropriately. So I find (by mistake) if you set `TotalWidth` the `TotalHeight` is automatically set/calculated.

Sanjay